# ng build not copying folder to dist

Tags: angular, typescript, protobuf.js

I am using [protobufjs-cli](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/master/cli/README.md) to generate a .js file from .proto files and then from the .js file I generate a .d.ts file, which is imported and used in various files in my project (using Angular 15).

When I run **ng build my-project** the folder containing the generated .js/.d.ts files is not copied to /dist.  As a result, ng build fails with:

```
Generating FESM2020
Could not resolve "../proto/ProtoDefs" from "dist/my-project/esm2020/rules/rules.mjs"
```

rules.ts has:

```
import root from "../proto/ProtoDefs";
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
  node_modules
  projects
    my-project
      src
        proto
          Protodefs.d.ts
          Protodefs.js
        rules
          rules.ts
```

How can I get the proto folder to be copied to /dist **before** the build starts so that the build does not fail?  Why isn't it copied like all of the other folders under src?

I am still pretty new to angular/typescript so am not sure if there is some setting in some config somewhere that I am missing.  Everything works fine when I run **ng serve** (no resolve errors).

Let me know if you need more info.